# I broke my sources.d file in my Linux Mint XFCE machine. How do I restore it?

Tags: linux

I'm very dumb and I somehow managed to break my sources.d file in the /etc/apt/ directory. Is there a way to restore it?

Comment: Can you update your post to include the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory, containing the sources for your system package manager. Alternative file paths include `/etc/apt/sources.list`, `/etc/apt/sources.d/*.list`, etc.

You can't really break it, as it is either 1) a directory containing further configuration files, or 2) a plain text file itself.